# Applying Z-Index to DropDownTree Doesn't Affect It

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik, css-position, z-index

When DropDownTree sits near other expanding controls (e.g. standard date pickers), causes these controls to sit behind DropDownTree. I tried every solution like sitting inline style, enforcing z-index to .RadDropDownTree_Default, making other controls' z-index attribute too much bigger than 100000 and enforcing style via jquery, but in any case, expanded controls fall behind the input (textbox) area of RadDropDownTree.

How can I enforce low z-index values on RadDropDownTree so that it does not sit above other expanding controls?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The RadDropDownTree dropdown has a default z-index value of 7000 as shown in this article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/controlling-absolute-positioning-with-zindex.html. To change it just set the z-index CSS property of RadDropDownTree to smaller value than the input elements.

If you are unable to solve the issue, share some code snippets which will help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, see if the DropDownTree parents have any special positioning or z-index settings.